# Can you get the "proc name" inside a proc?

Tags: tcl

Within a proc can you get the proc name (without hardcoding it)?  e.g.

```
proc my_proc { some_arg } {
    puts "entering proc [some way of getting proc name]"
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Of course you can!

Use `info level` command:

```
proc my_proc { some_arg } {
    puts "entering proc [lindex [info level 0] 0]"
}
```

and you get exactly what you want

```
entering proc my_proc
```

Another way is to use `info frame`, which gives a dictionary with some other info, and read the `proc` key:

```
proc my_proc { some_arg } {
    puts "entering proc [dict get [info frame 0] proc]"
}
```

this time, you'll get the fully qualified proc name:

```
entering proc ::my_proc
```

Comment: That should be `[lindex [info level 0] 0]`, because `info level 0` returns a list with the current proc's name **and arguments**.

Comment: `info level 0` gets you information about what it was _called as_, `info frame 0` gets you information about what it _is_. The two are usually closely related, but not always…

Comment: Donal, can you give an example of when the two are different? Since I didn't use it very often, in my experience I never see that difference. Thanks

Comment: @MarcoPallante, your own example is good. [info frame] returned ::my_proc while [info level] returned my_proc (without the ::).This will especially be different if you called ::ns1::proc1 from outside or inside the namespace.

Comment: Good point, @NirLevy, so to get something really equivalent, I should do `[lindex [info level 0] 0]` in one case, and `[namespace tail [lindex [info frame 0] 0]]`, right?

Comment: Yeah, unless @DonalFellows have some more extreme cases to enlighten us all.